# iPhone push notification connection frequecy

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Apple's documentation states

> You should also retain connections with APNs across multiple notifications. (APNs may consider connections that are rapidly and repeatedly established and torn down as a denial-of-service attack.)

What does this mean in practice?  How often can you open and close connections?  Are you supposed to always maintain a connection between the APNs and server, even if you have nothing to send it?

Comment: FYI, before implementing a Push provider yourself, you may want to look at a service like Urban Airship. I'm using it now and although I haven't gotten to production yet, it has worked great thus far.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility.  But I'm looking at the apn_on_rails plugin and if it works, I'm not sure there is much advantage of integrating with another service.